# Regex: string can contain spaces, but not only spaces. It cannot contain `*` nor `:` characters either

Tags: java, regex

I need help finding a regex that will allow most strings, except:

- if the string only contains whitespaces
- if the string contains `:` or `*`

I want to reject the following strings:

- `"hello:world"`
- `"hello*world"`
- `" "` (just a whitespace)

But the following strings will pass:

- `"hello world"`
- `"hello"`

So far, I can accomplish what I want... in two patterns.

- `[^:*]*` rejects the 2 special characters
- `.*\S.*` rejects any string with only whitespaces

I'm not sure how to combine these two patterns into one...

I'll be using the regex pattern along with Java.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?  Other ways are likely simpler.

Comment: @accessviolation, I'm curious to hear what the alternatives are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of how you could combine your two patterns for use with the `matches` method:

```java
"[^:*]*[^:*\\s][^:*]*"
```

`[^\s]` is equivalent to `\S`.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to combine the two patterns I had!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!\s*$)[^:*]+$
```

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?!\s*$)` negative lookahead rejecting whitespace-only strings
- `[^:*]+` - one or more of any character except `:` and `*`
- `$` - end of string anchor

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QXvgLH/1)

Comment: I ended up going with your solution, thanks for informing of negative lookaheads!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matches` to match the whole string with the doubled backslash:

```
\\s*[^\\s:*][^:*]*
```

**Explanation**

- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `[^\s:*]` Match a non whitespace char other than `:` and `*`
- `[^:*]*` Match optional chars other than `:` and `*`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXl1hl/1).

As `\s` can also match a newline, if you don't want to cross matching newlines:

```
\\h*[^\\s:*][^\\r\\n:*]*
```

**Explanation**

- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `[^\s:*]` Match a non whitespace char other than `:` and `*`
- `[^\\r\\n:*]*` Match optional chars other than `:` and `*` or newlines

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D6HmOm/1).

Comment: Nice! I think your second pattern meets the requirement precisely as he required the whitespace (just whitespace) to be rejected.